# Plot two dimensional array with "for" loop

Tags: python

I have Python classes on University, however I'm not into the programming stuff and I have a problem with one exercise.
We've got to create an array that looks like this:

[image: image of the array]

While having the list of x (from 1.0 to 10.0, as see in the array) and formulas for y1 and y2 which are: y1=sin(x) and y2=sin(x)*2.7^(-x).
My code looks like this:

```
x=[1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5, 9.0, 9.5, 10.0]
y1=[]
y2=[]
for i in x:
    l=math.sin(i)
    l=round(l, 5)
    y1.append(l)
for o in x:
    o=math.sin(o)*(pow(2.7, -o))
    o=round(o, 6)
    y2.append(o)
```

Can you help me how to get that three lists into one that looks like on the photo?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't understand what you mean by "array that looks like in the image". The image does not show any kind of array. The image shows some text with `|` and `-` symbols used to draw a diagram. If you don't confidently understand the assignment, you should show us the relevant portion of the assignment as written. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822 for more guidance.

Comment: Also, if something is plain text, [don't show us a picture of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) - show text formatted as code, if it's supposed to appear in a terminal window.

Comment: Most likely, the assignment is asking you to think about the problem logically, break it down step by step, and come up with a *process* that draws that diagram. For example, can you write code that produces the first or second lines of the output? (Hint: do these lines change depending on what is in the lists?) Can you write code that produces one of the other lines? (Hint: for a given line, what is the rule that tells you each value to use? Can you think of a way to output each value, and put the necessary amount of space in between and the `|` symbols?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First of all, welcome to StackOverflow!*

Essentially, what you need to do is go through your `x` *list* (the structures declared with square brackets in Python are *lists*, not *arrays* ) and, for each element, calculate either of those sine formulae you presented.

### Getting the numbers

You were on the right track, but you are missing a couple of things:

1. you forgot import the `math` module (or you omitted that line in your snippet).
2. to get an output on your console, you need to print your lists, `x`, `y1` and `y2`. Just add three prints at the end of your script, like this:

```py
# the print function will output everything you give it, separated by a space
print("x:", x)
print("y1:", y1)
print("y2:", y2)
```

Now, your script should output the following:

```
x: [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5, 9.0, 9.5, 10.0]                                                                                             
y1: [0.84147, 0.99749, 0.9093, 0.59847, 0.14112, -0.35078, -0.7568, -0.97753, -0.95892, -0.70554, -0.27942, 0.21512, 0.65699, 0.938, 0.98936, 0.79849, 0.41212, -0.07515, -0.54402]             
y2: [0.311656, 0.224836, 0.124732, 0.049961, 0.00717, -0.010846, -0.014241, -0.011194, -0.006683, -0.002992, -0.000721, 0.000338, 0.000628, 0.000546, 0.00035, 0.000172, 5.4e-05, -6e-06, -2.6e-0
5]
```

---

Some other notes:

- you don't need to change iteration variable names for each `for` loop.
- you don't need to use the `pow` function. Python has the `**` syntax, which behaves like the usual `^` (which has another meaning in this language already). So you could rewrite `pow(2.7, -o)` to `2.7**(-o)`.
- if you are not constrained to using `for` loops, you could also use the very handy `map` function. It applies a function over a given list, which is exactly what you're trying to achieve. You could "just" write:

```py
# not doing round to be shorter
y1 = list(map(lambda i: math.sin(i), x))
y2 = list(map(lambda i: math.sin(i)*2.7**(-i), x))
```

- alternatively, *list comprehensions* exist and are also very neat and would fit here well:

```py
y1 = [math.sin(i) for i in x]
y2 = [math.sin(i)*2.7**(-i) for i in x]
```

### Printing them in a table

Python has rather powerful string formatting, which makes printing these lists as tables pretty simple :D
The full code is as follows:

```py
# Construct the header
header = f"| {'x':10} | {'y1':10} | {'y2':10} |"
# enough dashes to underline the whole header
line = "-" * len(header)
print(header)
print(line)

# Iterate through the three lists and print them with appropriate 
# spacing and decimal places
for ix, iy1, iy2 in zip(x, y1, y2):
    print(f"| {ix:10.5f} | {iy1:10.5f} | {iy2:10.5f} |")

print("-" * len(header))  # print new dash line
```

I'm making use of *f-strings*, which makes formatting strings really easy. You just put an `f` before the opening quotes and then you can insert variables inside curly brackets. Additionally, you can tell Python how wide you want the inserted string to be, which is what those `10`s following the columns are. You can also specify how many decimal places you want, in case you're printing floats, which is done by adding those `.5f` (format float with 5 decimal places with a `.` as separator) after the width.
Finally, the `zip` function allows you to iterate multiple things at the same time. In this case, I used it to go through all three lists at the same time to print each of their values on the same lines.

### Final output

```
| x          | y1         | y2         |                                                                                                                                                        
----------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                        
|    1.00000 |    0.84147 |    0.31166 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    1.50000 |    0.99749 |    0.22484 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    2.00000 |    0.90930 |    0.12473 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    2.50000 |    0.59847 |    0.04996 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    3.00000 |    0.14112 |    0.00717 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    3.50000 |   -0.35078 |   -0.01085 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    4.00000 |   -0.75680 |   -0.01424 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    4.50000 |   -0.97753 |   -0.01119 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    5.00000 |   -0.95892 |   -0.00668 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    5.50000 |   -0.70554 |   -0.00299 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    6.00000 |   -0.27942 |   -0.00072 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    6.50000 |    0.21512 |    0.00034 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    7.00000 |    0.65699 |    0.00063 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    7.50000 |    0.93800 |    0.00055 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    8.00000 |    0.98936 |    0.00035 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    8.50000 |    0.79849 |    0.00017 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    9.00000 |    0.41212 |    0.00005 |                                                                                                                                                        
|    9.50000 |   -0.07515 |   -0.00001 |                                                                                                                                                        
|   10.00000 |   -0.54402 |   -0.00003 |
----------------------------------------
```

---

I hope this helps you, and feel free to ask questions in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import math

# You don't have to use one-liners of course, I just wanted the code to be shorter.
x = [i*0.5 for i in range(2, 21)]
y1 = [round(math.sin(i), 5) for i in x]
y2 = [round(math.sin(i)*pow(2.7, -i), 6) for i in x]
print(f'{"x":10} | {"y1":10} | {"y2":10}')  # print with spaces
print('_'*36) # underline
for l1, l2, l3 in zip(x, y1, y2):
    print(f'{l1:10} | {l2:10} | {l3:10}')
```

Output:

```py
x          | y1         | y2        
____________________________________
       1.0 |    0.84147 |   0.311656
       1.5 |    0.99749 |   0.224836
       2.0 |     0.9093 |   0.124732
       2.5 |    0.59847 |   0.049961
       3.0 |    0.14112 |    0.00717
       3.5 |   -0.35078 |  -0.010846
       4.0 |    -0.7568 |  -0.014241
       4.5 |   -0.97753 |  -0.011194
       5.0 |   -0.95892 |  -0.006683
       5.5 |   -0.70554 |  -0.002992
       6.0 |   -0.27942 |  -0.000721
       6.5 |    0.21512 |   0.000338
       7.0 |    0.65699 |   0.000628
       7.5 |      0.938 |   0.000546
       8.0 |    0.98936 |    0.00035
       8.5 |    0.79849 |   0.000172
       9.0 |    0.41212 |    5.4e-05
       9.5 |   -0.07515 |     -6e-06
      10.0 |   -0.54402 |   -2.6e-05
```

Comment: good answer, but it would be nice to explain a bit more what the code is doing :)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for :D 
Thanks you!